# What font is used in Sprite's ads & promos? (not logo)

Tags: fonts, font-identification, advertising

I'm looking for the font used by Sprite in their ads and promos, but I couldn't find it. Here's an example photo I took from their site:

[image: You Gotta Live Life One Lemon At A Time]

Comment: That "N" should be distinct enough to locate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Verlag Black Italic** by [Hoefler & Co.](https://www.typography.com/fonts/verlag/overview/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Looks very close to Town by Jason Vandenberg. The one difference I notice is with the A's.

Comment: Where can we (legally) obtain this typeface? It'd be great if you could add that info to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: It's $19. https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/greyscale-type/town/10-display-medium/

Comment: Thank you @ColorCodin, My apologies for not adding it before.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Century Gothic Italic + additional stroke for bolder look

looooooooong answer....even lebron dont want to read it. :-)

[image]

Comment: Just a shot of the text in Century Gothic with a stroke next to the ad would have been more than enough :) Thanks anyway! Do you have any idea where Century Gothic can be bought for those of us who don't have it?

Comment: I think Sir its only a pre-set typeface. in mac and windows.

Comment: the open/close quotes don't seem to match... Are you sure it's century gothic?

Comment: Hmm... it's very close but the Ts aren't connected in the original photo.

Comment: If you want to speed up the process yous just tweak it a little bit any way when its expanded you can adjust it. If you want the exact copy of the font seek it in a million selection :-)